# Is there any example to show how to write a DirectShow transform filter?

Tags: directshow

I want to capture a current frame and its previous one to do analysis and produce a new frame to show. Is it to say I must write a transform DirectShow filter? But I am a newbie to DirectShow. I was confused by MSDN's lots of documents. So I wonder if there is any simple example to show how to do it.

Thanks.
Cook

Comment: O, I found. There are some sample with DirectShow SDK. Either a NullIP or a NullNull filter sample project with none functionality is a good start for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the directshow samples that come with the Platform SDK you, at least, always USED to get examples on how to make all sorts of filters.  I can't believe they would have removed that.  It made DirectShow almost usable :)

This may help:

- [Writing Transform Filters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd391015.aspx)
- [EZRGB24 Filter Sample](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375634)