# DirectShow filter to detect specific frequencies

Tags: c++, filter, directshow

loving and gracious Internet community.  I am working on building an application that uses DirectShow to play HLS streams and run some processes on them.

I used Graphedt.exe to render the URL that we use and it works great, but we need to be able to detect specific sub-audible frequencies.  I assume that a filter would serve that purpose well.  Just not totally sure how to analyze the incoming frames for an audio frequency.

I am new to C++ programming but am willing to learn and work on it.

Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the default DirectSound audio renderer, then you should try writing a **TransInPlace** filter to Account the buffers flowed.

Furthermore, you can add a property page to be useful when debugging.

Comment: Any suggestions on where to go to find any tutorials on writing filters?  I'm having a hard time finding much of anything.

Comment: Okay, the most recommended tutorials will still be the official document.  

* [Writing Transform Filters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd391015(v=vs.85).aspx)
* [EZRGB24 Filter Sample](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375634)

 During my search, found the other [question answer related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1263904/is-there-any-example-to-show-how-to-write-a-directshow-transform-filter). He's much more experienced than me. LOL